# Is it possible to package c code with Haskell using cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have a c library that I'd like to provide an FFI interface for.  This is easy enough, but I can't figure out how to get the packaging right.  It would be nice to just be able to

```
cabal install librarybindings
```

and have cabal automatically build it with gcc, generate the .o file, and include that with the distribution.  Right now, I can the package to compile fine, but when you go to build an executable using the bindings you have to explicitly pass ghc the .o file on the command line.  Yuck.

Comment: Look at [zlib](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib), it does exactly this (on Windows).

Comment: Sure is, just see any existing library with C code for an example.  Ex: bloomfilter, cipher-aes, cipher-aes128, crypto-api, and so many more.  I think bloomfilter is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks. These examples are exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can ship C code with Haskell. See e.g.

- [bytestring](http://darcs.haskell.org/bytestring/)
- [zlib](http://code.haskell.org/zlib/)
- [download](http://code.haskell.org/~dons/code/download/)

By convention the C bits are put in a cbits/ directory.